# ArcGis Engine, how to select objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, arcgis

I'm trying to create a standalone application, which loads a ArcGis map, selects a few objects in one layer and zooms to them.

Loading and displaying the map does work, using something like this:

```
AxMapControl _mapControl;

// in constructor:
_mapControl = new AxMapControl();

// in loading
_mapControl.LoadMxFile(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\TestProject.mxd");
```

This does work nicely and does display the map as full extent (of course the AxMapControl is embedded into a WindowsFormsHost, but this shouldn't be a problem).

But now I need to select one or more objects and zoom to them. I tried to select in one layer for testing, but this does not work at all:

```
IFeatureSelection features = _mapControl.Map.Layer[0] as IFeatureSelection;
if (features != null)
{
  QueryFilter qf = new QueryFilterClass();
  qf.WhereClause = "[Name]='FS4711000'";
  features.SelectFeatures(qf, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, false);
}
```

on the SelectFeatures call I get an COM error 80004005 (E_Fail) in ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto, without much more explanation. Probably I'm doing it all wrong.

Maybe someone has a sample how to select objects in a layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is as simple as the `[square brackets]` around your field name in the query string.

This works:

```
IFeatureSelection features = _currentLayer as IFeatureSelection;
if (features != null)
{
    QueryFilter qf = new QueryFilter();
    qf.WhereClause = "Type='1'";

    features.SelectFeatures(qf, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, false);
}
_axMapControl.Refresh();
```

Whereas this fails with COM-error E_FAIL:

```
IFeatureSelection features = _currentLayer as IFeatureSelection;
if (features != null)
{
    QueryFilter qf = new QueryFilter();
    qf.WhereClause = "[Type]='1'";

    features.SelectFeatures(qf, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, false);
}
_axMapControl.Refresh();
```

Also, notice that the map (or at least the `IActiveView` returned by `AxMapControl.ActiveView`) needs to be manually refreshed, or the selection is not displayed before the map is redrawn.

Comment: Uhm, honestly, I tried with and without brackets, and had the error both ways. Now I tried again just to make sure, and it worked without brackets?!? Whatever you did to magically make my code work, thanks! :)

Comment: Programming against the poorly documented ESRI API takes more dumb luck, inventive guesswork and **pure black voodoo magic** than skill. Welcome to your worst nightmare :)

Comment: Oh dang, and I thought programming old Avenue scripts was my worst nightmare - but ESRI managed to top itself in creating nightmares? Poor me! :)

Comment: You don't happen to know how to zoom and pan into the selection? The Avenue ways don't give me any clue about this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/arcgis-engine-how-to-zoompan-to-selected-objects

Comment: @Sam I'm sure everything ESRI does is horrible. I think they hate developers. Answered your question on GIS.

Comment: Only other explanation would be, that ESRI has only clever sales people doing the programming as convoluted as they can, so they can sell you expensive training and help (there seems to be way more money in training&help than in license sales).