# ArcGis Engine, how to highlight some features/shapes?

Tags: .net, arcgis

In a standalone c#/wpf application using ArcGis Engine, I've loaded some shapes, [selected some features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141506/arcgis-engine-how-to-select-objects).

Now I want to highlight one of the selected features. I can find the object/feature on a IFeatureSelection/Layer, I've got the IGeometry from IFeature.Shape.

Is there an easy way to mark a known feature/shape, say, in red, or something like it?

I've got the feature using something like this:

```
AxMapControl _mapControl;
IFeatureSelection features = _mapControl.Map.Layer[0] as IFeatureSelection;
ICursor cursor;
features.SelectionSet.Search(null, true, out cursor);
IFeature feature;
while ((feature = ((IFeatureCursor)cursor).NextFeature()) != null)
{
  IGeometry geometry = feature.Shape;
}
```

I searched the samples, but was not able to find what I need.

Comment: You could also try: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
static public void FlashFeature(IFeature feature)
        {
            if (feature == null)
                return;
            IApplication app = ApplicationRef;
            IMxDocument doc = (IMxDocument)(app.Document);

            IFeatureIdentifyObj feature_identify_obj = new FeatureIdentifyObjectClass();
            feature_identify_obj.Feature = feature;
            ((IIdentifyObj)feature_identify_obj).Flash(doc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay);
        }
```

---

Where ApplicationRef is:

```
static public IApplication ApplicationRef
        {
            get
            {
                Type obj_type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(typeof(AppRefClass).GUID);

                IApplication obj = null;
                try
                {
                    obj = (IApplication)Activator.CreateInstance(obj_type);
                }
                catch {}

                return obj;
            }
        }
```

---

Or you can do it by creating graphics IElement element in IGraphicsContainer, smth like:

```
        void ShowFeature(IFeature feature)
        {
            element.Geometry = geometry.Project(mapSpatialReference, feature.Shape);

            graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);

            activeView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);

            featureHighlighted = true;
        }

        void HideFeature()
        {
            if (!featureHighlighted)
                return;

            graphicsContainer.DeleteElement(element);

            activeView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);

            featureHighlighted = false;
        }
```

Comment: First solution does not work, I get a COM Exception when calling Activator.CreateInstance for ApplicationRef: 80040154 Class not registered (HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).